# How to load a BMP file using wxPython on Windows?

Tags: windows, wxpython

It seems that wxPython is missing "some" examples.

I have the following piece of code that doesn't work on Windows:

```
import wx
wx.InitAllImageHandlers() # calling it doesn't make any difference 
print wx.Image("sample.bmp") # also tried with type=wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY
```

The returned value is `None` and I can also see a warning: `Warning: No handler found for image type.`

I tried to add the second line but it seems that it doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Strange, the WX docs say that the BMP handler is always available. I suppose you're able to load `sample.bmp` in mspaint without problems?

Comment: Yep, it loads in Paint and also I opened and saves the image with Pain-t and even if now has a different size it doesn't load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need `wx.App` created first.

```
import wx

app = wx.App(False)
print wx.Image("wallpaper.bmp")
```

Comment: There may be a bug with `wx.InitAllImageHandlers()` not working properly. `wx.App` also initializes the handlers. But maybe nobody noticed, it is uncommon to use it that way.

Comment: Hmm, the docs say: InitAllImageHandlers() - The former functionality of InitAllImageHanders is now done internal to the \_core\_ extension module and so this function has become a simple NOP.

Comment: This means the wxPython s**** big time, and it's far from being a pythonic library. Now it loads 2/3 images, and complains about invalid image on one of them, still the same images is loaded without any problems in 4 different applications.

Comment: Can you share the broken image?

Comment: Let's do it the proper way, here is the link to the bug http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/13650 where you will find the BMP file attached to.